# DNS query in Java

Tags: java, dns, inetaddress

I am messing around with DNS services in Java. I am specifically trying to look up all google.com addresses and display them in an array, similar to running a lookup using [`nslookup`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nslookup):

```
nslookup -q=TXT _netblocks.google.com 8.8.8.8
```

I am using `InetAddress` for this but I keep on getting exceptions. Since the exceptions refer to an 'Unknown Host', I don't think `InetAddress` can read TXT records (if I use google.com it works, but that doesn't show the full IP range).

Below is my code:

```
InetAddress dnsresult[] = InetAddress.getAllByName("_netblocks.google.com");

for (int i=0; i<dnsresult.length; i++)
    System.out.println(dnsresult[i]);
```

I would appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: This problem may not be Java related only since my `ping` also can't resolve `_netblocks.google.com`.

Comment: Thanks Zhedar, I know that :) I added that to illustrate what I am trying to do. If I use 'google.com' as my argument, it does pop out an IP. But that is the A record. I need to grab the TXT record.

Answer (score 12):

You **cannot** lookup TXT or other DNS records `InetAddress` class. `InetAddress.getAllByName()` looks up for *A*, or *AAAA* records only.

Check [DNS Java](http://www.xbill.org/dnsjava/) for your needs.

Answer (score 6):

Here is an example that does what you are trying to do:

```
Attribute attr = new InitialDirContext().getAttributes("dns:_netblocks.google.com", new String[] {"TXT"}).get("TXT");
System.out.println("attr.get() = " + attr.get());
System.out.println("attr.getAll() = " + Collections.list(attr.getAll()));
```

If you want to use a custom dns server use "dns://1.1/_netblocks.google.com" instead.

Answer (score 5):

`InetAddress` doesn't do this, but you can accomplish DNS TXT record lookups in Java via the [JNDI DNS provider](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jndi/jndi-dns.html).

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using Google's "JSON API for DNS over HTTPS (DoH)"

https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/doh/json